# Why won't Xcode recognize a typedef from a header that's being properly imported?

Tags: objective-c, ios, typedef

I used to have a class called `Constants`. In it was this `typedef`:

```
typedef enum visible_thing {

    BACKGROUND,
    BACKGROUND_COLOR,
    MAIN_WINDOW

} VISIBLE_THING;
```

And my, was life rosy! I was importing 'Constants.h` wherever I needed to access this type, and it all worked.

Then I decided to nuke the `Constants` class. I took the typedef and I put it in another class, for clarity let's call it `OtherClass`. I went through and changed all the imports of `Constants.h` to imports of `OtherClass.h` That's all I did, I didn't touch any other code. And now the whole thing's broke!

Methods that worked perfectly with `Constants` now give me this error: `Parse Issue - Expected a type`. What the heck? I sure hope someone has some leads on this!

Update: frustratingly, this is one of those problems that just seemed to go away on its own without explanation. I answered my own question, below, with a workaround I'd found that entailed #import-ing the same header multiple times in one file. But today I removed the extra #import, and everything still worked. Arg. Computers!

Comment: Did you first try out a simple demo project to see if you an reproduce the problem? I'd bet anything I can do so and have the system respond exactly as would be expected. If in fact you or I did that, then the question becomes, what could produce the outcome you report below The only think I can think of is some "#undefine". Please edit your question and supply the version of Xcode and if this is ObjectiveC++ or just ObjectiveC code.

Comment: @DavidH I seem to have found the solution to the issue, which I explained in an answer below. Are you saying there's a problem with my solution? If so, please explain more in a reply to the solution itself. I'm assuming you're the person who down-voted it, it would help to have some explanation of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class that was generating the errors had two other class definitions inside it, helper classes that were only used internally. Apparently that was the root of the problem.

What I didn't know was that if you do that, if there is more than one class in a file, you may need to import the same header multiple times.

Here's what I did to fix it. I changed this:

```
#import "OtherClass.h"

@interface InnerClass

// uses typedef from OtherClass

@end



@interface MainClass

// uses typedef from OtherClass

@end
```

To this:

```
#import "OtherClass.h"

@interface InnerClass

// uses typedef from OtherClass

@end

#import "OtherClass.h" //<--without this, MainClass won't recognize the typedef 

@interface MainClass

// uses typedef from OtherClass

@end
```

Which seems clunky and like I may be doing something else wrong, but at least it fixed the issue at hand. Any follow-up comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Having multiple classes in one file seems a little odd. Why did you do that?

Comment: I see multiple classes in one file frequently enough, including in Apple's iOS code examples and in Objective-C text books. I guess it can be a way to keep a helper class together with the class that it's used in, if the helper class is not intended to be reused for anything else. I've never done it myself, but I've certainly seen it done. That said, I don't think that you should have to import the same file twice in one file, as my understanding is that #import essentially just copies the code from the file you're importing into your file. SOmething strange seems to be happening here.

Comment: @Darren I've seen it many times myself, and I don't really know if there are any rules about when and how you should or shouldn't do it. I couldn't really find any online, but maybe I was using the wrong search terms. Anyway, it does seem to be weird to do multiple #import statements, but for now I guess I'm going with "if it ain't broke, don't fix it." As kludges go, it seems fairly harmless. Do you think I'm risking major trouble by not hunting it down further?

Comment: I posted an answer, because my comments were too long to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same "Expected a type", and it turns out that it was caused by an imports loop. I reproduced it with the following simple example:

**A.h:**

```
#import "B.h"

typedef enum {
    SomeEnumA
} SomeEnum;

@interface A : NSObject

@end
```

**B.h:**

```
#import "A.h"

@interface B : NSObject

- (void) func:(SomeEnum)arg;

@end
```

The compiler complains about SomeEnum unknown in B.h - while compiling A.m (which just imports A.h). This happens because A.h imports B.h which imports A.h. The imports loop doesn't occur, so B.h in this case does not include the A.h code where the type is defined.

The issue can be easily solved by moving the definition of the enum to a separate SomeEnum.h .

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try to figure out what's going on, because what ever is causing this to happen might cause other mysterious bugs in the future, and by that point you might have forgotten about this, which could make it more difficult to track down the cause of the future bugs.

I would try to isolate the problem. A few things that you could try:

- progressively commenting out code in the InnerClass interface to see if you can get the problem to go away.
- manually adding a typedef at the top of your file with a different type name (and editing the rest of your code appropriately) to see if the problem is still there.
- posting your .h file and OtherClass.h file to see if anyone else can spot the problem
- David H's suggestion of creating a demo project to see if you can reproduce the problem

I think it depends on what your project is, if it's just something small and fast that you want to get working, it probably doesn't matter, but if it's going to be a larger project and you forsee your code base expanding, or if it's something that other coders are going to be working on as well, I would try to understand what's happening here.

Comment: Actually, before any of that, shouldn't we confirm that this is aberrant behavior? You and I both, I think, are admittedly unfamiliar with how these things work. We're just guessing that there's a problem, because it seems clunky. Is there some way to confirm authoritatively that this is a bug, before doing all that testing?

Comment: Actually, rereading the question again, you said yourself that everything was working normally when you were using the Constants class, so I think we can be confident that something is wrong here.

Comment: Ha, just read your updated question. Maybe it was a quirk in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled into this one while trying to create a Framework. Xcode didn't like the typedef to be defined above the interface. Not sure why this is, but it fixed it.

So I changed mine from:

```c
typedef enum {
   MyOption1,   // option 1.
   MyOption2,   // option 2.
}MyOption;

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;

@end
```

to:

```c
@interface MyClass : NSObject

typedef enum {
   MyOption1,   // option 1.
   MyOption2,   // option 2.
}MyOption;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myString;

@end
```